# assigning int literal to Long in java

Tags: java, wrapper, literals, primitive

I see no clear rationale for happening this ..

```
public  class wrappers
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        short s1=32767; // (primitive) works fine without compile error
        short s2=32768;   fails as this is  beyond short's range


        Short s3=32767; //(wrapper) works fine without compile error
        Short s4=32768; fails as this is beyond short's range

        long l1 =34   // (wrapper)works fine (with_in_range)


        Long l2 =34    // fails, without 34L (with_in_range)

    }
```

I know that when you assign `int` literal for wrapper classes, `valueOf()` is called;

while  for `Short(Wrapper)` this seems to work  but for `Long(wrapper)` above assignments in code fail.

Are there any rules governing these wrapper classes' assignments?

Comment: You found a nice corner case. I believe, the `Short s4 = 32767` shouldn't work either. Anyway, you can fix the `Long` case like this: `Long l1 = 12L; // capital L`.
For the record, the term for this called [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), you can google for that.

Comment: Yes, there are rules. They are called the [Java Language Specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

Comment: You aren't casting the values. just like `int a = 100.1` doesn't compile, same for above.

Comment: @TamasRev i suppose  short range is -32768 to 32767 and i know this is autoboxing, this assignments are syntactic sugar for valueOf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on Jon's answer, the rule that allows `Short s3=32767` to work is also specified in the JLS. There's a special rule regarding assignment of constant expressions :

> [5.2. Assignment Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) 
> ...
>
> In addition, if the expression is a **constant expression**  (§15.28) of
> type byte, short, char, or **int**:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant
>   expression is representable in the type of the variable.
> - **A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may be used if the type of the variable is**:
>
>   1. Byte and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type byte.
>   2. **Short and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type short.**
>   3. Character and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type char.

Answer (score 5):

> are there any rules governing these wrapper classes' assignments

Yes - the rules of the JLS. It specifies [widening primitive conversions (5.1.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) and [boxing conversions (5.1.7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7).

The list of boxing conversions includes:

> - From type `int` to type `Integer`
> - From type `long` to type `Long`

So you want a widening conversion followed by a boxing conversion. You're trying to do this in an *assignment context* (5.2) which states:

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by a widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.

Note that this list does *not* include a widening primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion. The reverse is okay:

```
Integer x = 10;
long y = x; // Unboxing followed by widening primitive
```

On the face of it, it sounds like the rules *could* have been written to allow a widening primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion, with rules such that `Object x = 10;` prefers boxing as `Integer` rather than `Long`... but type conversion rules are *very* hard to get right, with lots of subtleties. I wouldn't be surprised if it turned out there are some bizarre situations where it would cause big problems.

The reason the conversion to `Short` works is due to further rules in 5.2:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.
> - A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may be used if the type of the variable is:
>
>   - `Byte` and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type `byte`.
>   - `Short` and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type `short`.
>   - `Character` and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type `char`.

In the case of

```
Short s = 32767;
```

there's a narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion as described above.

Comment: You should also mention the section allowing a narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion for the `Short s3=32767;` case.

Comment: You don't explain why the `Short s3=32767` works, given that literal `32767` is defined to be an `int` literal, so it should fail.

Comment: @Andreas: Have added that extra part.

Comment: @user2357112: Have done that now.

Answer (score 2):

Autoboxing is only done between the primitive type and their respective wrapper classes like:

> **int to Integer**,
>
> **long to Long**,
>
> **double to Double**  and so on.

Java *does not allow conversion between primitive type int and the Object Long.*
However, it does allow conversion between primitive type int and long.
Hence if you need to assign an int to a variable of type Long you need to add the suffix **l** or **L**:

```
  Long l2 =34L,
```